# nginx rewrite config

Tags: nginx, subdomain, rewrite, php-fpm, regex

I'm pretty new to nginx and am trying to setup some pretty simple rewrite rules, but they don't seem to be working.

Just for your info, this `server { .. }` has its `server_name domain.com *.domain.com`.

I have this `rewrite ^ /index.php?/$request_uri;` which seems to work great. This will match domain.com/asd/sad/sad and everything works as it should.

However, i'd like to do something funky with subdomains... so I have `s1.domain.com` and `s198.domain.com` but I would like to change my rewrite so it goes to `/index.php?/s1/$request_uri` if that makes sense? So the subdomain goes in before the `$request_uri`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
if ($host ~* ^([a-z]+)\..*) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1/$request_uri;
}
rewrite ^ /index.php?/$request_uri;
```

Really appreciate any help you can give!

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting method of parameterizing the path -- I would have gone for something like `/index.php?q=$request_uri`, but if this is what works for you...

Comment: I'm using [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com) and the site is currently running under Apache2 with this RewriteRule

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\..*`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/dev/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

The first of all: use of `if` is discouraged by Nginx author for a very good reason: it has very nasty side-effects. You may still use it in simple use-cases, but using `if` and `rewrite` simultaneously is like a bomb.

Your use case can be easily implemented using two `server` sections:

```
server {
  server_name domain.com;

  rewrite ^ /index.php?/$request_uri last;
}

server {
  server_name ~ ^(?<SUB>.+)\.domain.\com$ ;

  rewrite ^ /index.php?/$SUB/$request_uri last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your rule to

```
rewrite ^ /index.php?/$host/$request_uri;
```

but unfortunately that gets you "paths" like '/index.php?/s1.domain.com/asd/sad/sad', not '/index.php?/s1/asd/sad/sad' as you appear to be after.

Can you simply use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable in your PHP script and figure out the appropriate change within your script itself instead of making nginx do all the work?

**Edited to add:**

Wrote this before you posted your comment about FuelPHP; don't know what that is, but I presume it means you're either unable or unwilling (not that that's a bad thing) to make a change to the script as I suggested. Although the Apache rule you posted there doesn't automatically do what you're asking for any given subdomain, either -- it works for dev.domain.com, but none other.

Comment: FuelPHP is a framework :) I'm using its awesome HMVC functionality here, they allow you to separate out controllers/views/models into a modular system and then they are all namespaced under /module/controller/foo/bar. I was hoping for nginx to be able to grab the first segment of the domain and use that as the module...

Comment: Since I still use apache for local development and staging, I don't want to have to modify any application code for this to work.

Comment: @user18404: You can, it's even in the main nginx introduction: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html Also. Remember to use the fastcgi_split_path_info directive and turn off cgi.fix_pathinfo in PHP so that you aren't likely to be vulnerable to arbitary code execution.